# CollapsingToolbarLayout Title with ellipsize marquee

Tags: android, material-design

I want to use android's `CollapsingToolbarLayout` but have a title that, if the layout is collapsed, scrolls horizontally instead of being truncated. 
I tried calling `setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance` with the following style but that didn't have any effect on the marquee (only text color and size).

```
<style name="TitleText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/material_blue_600</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:marqueeRepeatLimit">marquee_forever</item>
</style>
```

Did I miss something? What's the best way to achieve this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but afaik marquee is only working if the `TextView` is focused. Since the `TextView` in the toolbar will never be focused, you would have to create some custom solution

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem myself trying to ellipsize a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. After an investigation into where in the android SDK the `TitleTextAppearance` is handled, it seems like only a handful of text appearance directives are respected:

`textColor`, `textSize`, `shadowColor`, `shadowDy`, `shadowDx`, `shadowRadius`, and `typeface`.

The `CollapsingToolbarLayout` class uses a `CollapsingTextHelper` to apply the text appearance, see the relevant method below:

```
void setCollapsedTextAppearance(int resId) {
    TintTypedArray a = TintTypedArray.obtainStyledAttributes(mView.getContext(), resId,
            android.support.v7.appcompat.R.styleable.TextAppearance);
    if (a.hasValue(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.styleable.TextAppearance_android_textColor)) {
        mCollapsedTextColor = a.getColorStateList(
                android.support.v7.appcompat.R.styleable.TextAppearance_android_textColor);
    }
    if (a.hasValue(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.styleable.TextAppearance_android_textSize)) {
        mCollapsedTextSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
                android.support.v7.appcompat.R.styleable.TextAppearance_android_textSize,
                (int) mCollapsedTextSize);
    }
    mCollapsedShadowColor = a.getInt(
            android.support.v7.appcompat.R.styleable.TextAppearance_android_shadowColor, 0);
    mCollapsedShadowDx = a.getFloat(
            android.support.v7.appcompat.R.styleable.TextAppearance_android_shadowDx, 0);
    mCollapsedShadowDy = a.getFloat(
            android.support.v7.appcompat.R.styleable.TextAppearance_android_shadowDy, 0);
    mCollapsedShadowRadius = a.getFloat(
            android.support.v7.appcompat.R.styleable.TextAppearance_android_shadowRadius, 0);
    a.recycle();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        mCollapsedTypeface = readFontFamilyTypeface(resId);
    }
    recalculate();
}
```

As Lovis said, if you want the ellipsize directive to be respected you're going to have to implement your own `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `CollapsingTextHelper` classes.

Full Source for the `CollapsingTextHelper` class: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/android-7.1.1_r23/design/src/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingTextHelper.java